# Can a logo have two symbols?

Tags: logo, symbols

I’ve just made this logo for a client. I hit on the idea of making the *dd* of “saddle” a bicycle. But the client also liked the mock up of the saddle with call out sign (to the right of Swag).

Now the client wants to use both of these ideas and I’ve added them together to make a complete logo. I was just wondering whether having two symbols in the logo will divide the viewer’s attention. Will that be a problem?

[image: Saddle Swag logo]

Comment: Are you asking for a general critique or just about 2 symbols in general?

Comment: What is mobile advertising? is it related to mobile phones?

Comment: Especially being in such a bright green it took a long time for my brain to process a bike seat from above. I thought it was a beaker representing some kind of chemical.

Comment: @DA01 i'm asking for both :-)

Comment: Perhaps not answering your question, but right now it kinda looks like it reads "Sao oleSwag". As a rule of thumb, I would only turn letters into symbols or objects when it doesn't disrupt readability.

Comment: I can read this without problems. I think the bikes and the saddle are fine. I would however use one font and one color only. Not a designer though, just an opinion.

Answer (score 9):

In general, no, you don't want more than one 'aha' element in a logo. That's not to say you can't, or no one has, but it's a tough thing to pull off successfully.

In this particular example, you actually have 3 things going on...the 'bike', the 'saddle' and the 'speech bubble'. And I do think they are all competing. None of them stand out in terms of scale or weight and all become details rather than the focus (especially at smaller sizes).

Comment: I agree. I'd get rid of the bike in the dd and stick with the speech bubble/saddle. You'll never see the bike details on a business card or a website masthead.

Comment: this logo is a combination of 2 drafts. one with saddle callout sign and other with bicycle. The client insisted to combine both of them. So I did, and she likes it. You are right about the focus points btw :-)

Comment: @Ahmed in that case, do the work, take the check, and go on to the next project. You win some, you lose some. :)

Comment: @Ahmed Client asked you to do something, you did it, they like it - where's the problem? Who knows, maybe they know their target demographic and feel it will be a hit. You can only do so much before you have to let them run their company and you run yours.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to go for minimalism is my designs, so I normally go for one symbol. I agree with another comment of sticking to one color and one font, which will also simplify things down the road with printing and other coordinating identity elements. If it were me, I'd stick with the "saddle" font and symbol, and pick one color. I'd explain to the client that simplifying the logo is necessary to get the idea across in an instant first impression.

I completely disagree that the first bike symbol is difficult to read. The only area where I see readability issues is with the green color.

Great work!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you'll have to go with what the client wants, otherwise they'll be unhappy.
Perhaps you could try and combine both of these elements into one symbol. Presented nicely, the client should be happy that all elements of their design are present.

On a side note, that green is quite fluro and is difficult to read against a white background.

Comment: "Generally you'll have to go with what the client wants" = no. You need to sell them on the solution and *convince* them that's what they *need*. :)

Comment: Oh i completely agree with you there, but more often than not the client will be stubborn and won't accept that you're the expert in the field ;)

Comment: @Mushu_Pork then why do they hire you instead of a Photoshop monkey? :)

Comment: @Bakabaka: Because their assumption is that if they hire a professional, they will get *exactly* what they had sketched on their own, and (because it was done by a professional) it is guaranteed to be good and effective. (And if it isn't, they know who to blame.)

Comment: A teacher once thought me that you don't need to make your client happy, but you're client's clients.

Comment: I also like the mantra "The client is always right--but it's your job to make sure you convince the client what is right in the first place."

Answer (score 0):

Focus on the main thing,  everything else is noise. 
I love the idea of dd shown as bicycle but i don't like that implementation. Even the green is quite wierd. I think you have to choose and deeply explore your way.

Comment: To make this answer more useful, expand your answer with concrete information. "Like" and "don't like" are subjective opinions, not reasons.

Comment: I cannot agree with your statement, in graphic design like and don't like aren't subjective opinions, if you prefer I could rewrite my statement with other world: "The bicycle idea is difficult to realize preserving legibility, the green swag is too strong compared to the red saddle. In Logo design you have to show a strong idea with strong impact, everything else is noise, distraction from the main brand message"